# Pearson Correlation Question

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I am a beginner on calculating correlations and I would like to ask possibly a very simple question.

If I have two variables that I want to perform correlation on, and those variable are of unequal size, does this affect my correlation result?

Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate asserts (correctly) that "This scaling [in the calculation of correlation] makes correlation invariant to changes in scale of the original variables..."

Comment: So if I have sample size of a=300,b=210 calculating the correlation of a with b, that's fine then, i.e. b doesn't have to be 300 as well?

Comment: It now sounds that you are using "size" to mean "count."  You cannot even begin calculating correlation on such data: they have to be paired.